# Discord bot that appears in log survey when profile changes

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord

Discord bot that appears in log survey when profile changes

```
@client.event
async def on_member_update(before, after):
    if before.id == after.id:
        if before.avatar != after.avatar:
            past_profile = past_profiles.get(after.id, None)
            embed = discord.Embed(title='Profile')
            if past_profile:
                embed.set_author(icon_url=past_profile)
            embed.set_thumbnail(url=after.avatar_url)
            server = after.guild
            channel = server.get_channel(Channel_ID)
            await channel.send(embed=embed)
            past_profiles[after.id] = after.avatar_url
```

Discord bot that appears as a log survey when the profile changes.
However, the terminal does not display an error and does not output to the channel